# Retrieve the claims using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

The project I am working on is storing data inside the claim that I need to retrieve. The project is using Simple Injector as its IoC container and I have implemented the EnableHttpRequestMessageTracking as detailed in their article:

[Getting the current request’s HttpRequestMessage](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#getting-the-current-request-s-httprequestmessage)

However when attempting to get the values from the claims as part of the request it comes back null. This was working before the Simple Injector implementation by retrieving the values from the controller ActionContext.RequestContext but that was only available in the controller and the values are needed for a dependency that is injected into the controller.

Update (Actual Code):

```
      private void ConfigureIoc(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle(); 
        container.Options.DefaultLifestyle = Lifestyle.Scoped;

        container.RegisterSingleton<IRequestMessageAccessor>(new RequestMessageAccessor(container));
        container.Register<IConnectionStringGenerator, ConnectionStringGenerator>();
        container.Register(() => container.GetInstance<DataAccess.IDataAccessConfigurationFactory>().GetConfiguration(container.GetInstance<IConnectionStringGenerator>().GetConnectionString()));
        container.Register<DataAccess.Repositories.Lookups.ILookupRepository, DataAccess.Repositories.Lookups.SQLLookupRepository>();

        container.EnableHttpRequestMessageTracking(config);
        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);

        container.Verify();

        //app.Use(async (context, next) => { using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container)) { await next(); } });
        config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

And here is the rest:

```
public class ConnectionStringGenerator : IConnectionStringGenerator
{
    public IRequestMessageAccessor RequestMessage { get; set; }

    public ConnectionStringGenerator(IRequestMessageAccessor request)
    {
        RequestMessage = request;
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        if (RequestMessage.CurrentMessage != null)
        {
            var requestContext = RequestMessage.CurrentMessage.GetRequestContext();
            if (requestContext != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(PrincipalInformationExtractor.GetInfo(requestContext.Principal, "dbServer"));

                var dbServer = PrincipalInformationExtractor.GetInfo(requestContext.Principal, "dbServer");
                var dbName = PrincipalInformationExtractor.GetInfo(requestContext.Principal, "dbName");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbServer) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbName))
                {
                    return string.Format($"Server={dbServer};Database={dbName};Trusted_Connection=True");
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public interface IConnectionStringGenerator
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}

public sealed class RequestMessageAccessor : IRequestMessageAccessor
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public RequestMessageAccessor(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage CurrentMessage =>
        this.container.GetCurrentHttpRequestMessage();
}


public interface IRequestMessageAccessor
{
    HttpRequestMessage CurrentMessage { get; }
}

public static class PrincipalInformationExtractor
{
    public static string GetInfo(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal objPrincipal, string dataKey)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var principal = objPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal != null)
        {
            var value = principal.FindFirst(dataKey);
            if (value != null)
            {
                result = value.Value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now putting this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    PrincipalInformationExtractor.GetInfo(requestContext.Principal, "dbServer"));
```

In the controller like below yields a value:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
    PrincipalInformationExtractor.GetInfo(ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal, "dbServer"));
```

Any input on how to get those values?

Comment: Is the correct identity name at least still being retrieved?  Is it only missing your claims, or is the whole Principal wrong?

Comment: Please show both the working code and the non-working code.

Comment: @Mitch the entire principal is wrong it does not have any of the identity or claim information.

Comment: @Steven This is as much of the code I am allowed to share. The RequestMessageAccessor looks exactly as it does in the linked article. The code segment above is from a function within a class that takes the RequestMessageAccessor as a constructor parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can't expect us to guess what you are doing. Please show  that code.

Comment: @Steven Updated the post with the actual code blocks